# Reference request for texts on axiomatic geometry

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry

I am looking for papers and texts on axiomatic geometry, specifically Euclidean geometry. Now, I know axiomatic Euclidean geometry is a field with very little research currently going on, but I would still be interested in such papers. I am also interested in papers that talk about geometries that satisfy some but not all of the axioms of Euclidean geometry, such as absolute geometry (which is Euclidean geometry without the parallel postulate), and others.

Comment: Try [Hartshorne](https://maa.org/press/maa-reviews/geometry-euclid-and-beyond).

Comment: my short article  http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Intelligencer_1995.pdf  and  a later piece by Marvin  https://maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Greenberg2011.pdf

Comment: try this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_geometry#Hilbert's_axioms

Comment: pay attention to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_geometry#References

Comment: The book by [Lee](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/amstext-21) is also nice.